# process.env not available under SPA mode in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I put ENV params in an individual env.json and require it in nuxt.config.js, then extract the content into the env property of nuxt.config.js.

Under *Universal* and *Static* mode, it works good. But under *SPA* mode, it bumps a TypeError with message:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

env.json:

```
{
  "site": {
    "name": "Site Name",
    "slogan": "Some Cool Line",
    "description": "..."
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
const env = require('./env')

export default {
  mode: 'spa',

  env: {
    ...env
  },

  head: {
    titleTemplate: (page_title) => {
      return page_title
          ? page_title + ' | ' + process.env.site.name
          : process.env.site.name + ' - ' + process.env.site.slogan
    },

...
```

Any sparks on how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the similar thing and this is what I did

```
env: {
  ...env
},

// Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
head: {
  // titleTemplate: '%s - nuxt-https',
  titleTemplate: (page_title) => {
    return this
      ? page_title + ' | ' + this.default.env.site.name // process.env.site.name
      : process.env.site.name + ' - ' + process.env.site.slogan
  },
  title: 'Initial Title',
  ...
},
```